# Opinions please - switching legacy DB from CHAR(14) PKs to INT

Tags: mysql

I am administering a MySQL db for a payments processing system. For various legacy reasons it was originally built using CHAR(14) for many of the primary keys, which store a sequential ID based on a prefix identifying the type of data followed by a base36 encoded string representing a large number in sequence, e.g.

'PA00003NFMWHMQ' translating to 'payment 286103946050'

The advantage here is a semi-unique key that is still sequential, disadvantage being large values used for both clustered and non-clustered indexes, slowing down joins and lookups and requiring extra memory/storage.

I'm considering migrating them all to integers prior to releasing an API although I like the uniqueness too. I'm also wary of premature optimisation.

I'm not looking for a definite answer here, only some experienced opinions.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Andrew. And welcome. "*The advantage here is a semi-unique key that is still sequential*" Could you explain this some more? Primary keys need to be unique, so I don't understand why "semi-unique" would be an advantage. An auto incremented integer would definitely be unique. Do you mean unique for different rows in different tables?

Comment: Hi Schwen - I mean unique within the system, unlike an integer where id 10183 refers to different rows across many table.

Comment: In that case, UUIDv4 identifiers would be the way to go. And you probably want them for your API anyway, they're non-sequential. But I'd hesitate to use them for your primary key and probably stick with an integer for simplicity. Unless you have a concrete use case for cross-table unique IDs? Like, say, having multiple tables joined with the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is "are you going to have to hang onto this ID for backwards compatibility anyway?" IDs that have meaning, like yours, tend to get stored and referenced in external systems. Will you wind up with a table that has an integer primary key for internal use and a `char(14)` legacy id and two indexes? That may still be an improvement, but it impacts whether this change is worth it. Keep this in mind in the rest of my commentary.

If you can switch completely to auto incremented integers and get rid of special ID generation code, that should certainly make things simpler and inserts faster. How much simpler and faster you need to determine. Is it just one extra function somewhere deep in the creation code that doesn't bother anybody? Or is does it impact the code and design all over the place?

---

> *...disadvantage being large values used for both clustered and non-clustered indexes, slowing down joins and lookups and requiring extra memory/storage.*

As with any performance claim, the first thing would be to investigate if they're true. Is a `char(14)` key really slowing down joins and consuming memory and storage?

A `char(14)` (14 bytes) isn't much larger than an integer (4 bytes). The extra 10 bytes per row is just 10 MB per million records. But that's just to store the key. Every reference adds another 10 bytes. And every index featuring it another 10+ bytes. Still, I wouldn't assume this is a major storage and memory issue without measuring it.

Disk and memory are generally much cheaper than developer time. This doesn't mean to be wasteful, but consider whether saving a few gigs is worth however long this is likely to take (and the testing). Or if you can buy a bigger disk and more memory instead. For example, I have one project that could benefit from using enum fields instead of strings. But I haven't bothered because that would mean more developer time to make the change, and also to maintain the enum field. Instead it's still cheaper to pay for extra disk. That may change, and when it does I'll reconsider.

Similar with joins. If they're indexed, they should perform well regardless of whether it's a `char` or `int`. But you need testing.

I'd suggest you make a sanitized copy of the database, or generate one of decent size perhaps using your test factories, and run some performance tests with `char(14)` and with `int`. Be sure to test reality and whether this change will have a real impact on performance. Just running bare SQL queries may give you an outsized impression of their impact on performance. Also call the real functions you'd use in production, they might be swamping any SQL impact.

---

> *'PA00003NFMWHMQ' translating to 'payment 286103946050'*
>
> *I'm considering migrating them all to integers prior to releasing an API*

Exposing primary keys (or any other piece of implementation information) to the outside world has security and compatibility considerations. Its knowledge an attacker can use, for example they can predict what the next key will be. Don't do it.

Instead, assign each thing you're exposing a random API ID like a [UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) (don't use MySQL's UUID function, it is guessable UUIDv1). [Store them as `binary(16)`](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/) if space is a big concern.

Then it doesn't matter what your primary key is. You can change your design when you like.

---

> *The advantage here is a semi-unique key that is still sequential...*

This is a puzzler. Primary keys must be unique, so I'm not sure what you mean by "semi-unique". Do you mean across tables? That the ID of a row in column A is *probably* unique from the row in column B? If that's the case, consider UUID primary keys. Or consider whether this is truly an advantage that you can actually use because of the *semi* part.

Comment: By semi-unique I meant unique across tables, which has some utility. I'm going to leave it as is for now, I'm not seeing any performance hurdles just yet.